# Capitalize all words

Tags: javascript, regex

How to capitalize all words in a string excluding some hardcoded cases? For example:
words to exclude: "de", "la"
input: "DEGAS-URB.JARDÍN DE LAS AVENIDAS"
output: "Degas-Urb.Jardín de las Avenidas"

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function on each words:

```
function toTitleCase(str)
{
    // Protected words that you don't want to Titlecase
    var dontChangeTheseWords = ["de", "la"];
    if(dontChangeTheseWords.indexOf(str) > -1)
    {
        return str;
    }

    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}
```

Comment: It returns "Degas-urb.jardín De Las Avenidas". Results should be "Degas-Urb.Jardín de las Avenidas"

Comment: Because you split on spaces instead of word boundaries